# How to align child views of a toolbar vertically on a baseline?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I would like to use the Android Toolbar with two child views.
Both child views have the same text size but different fonts.

The following snippet centers both children vertically but the button is a bit heighter than the TextView.

My question is: How can I align both children on a real baseline?

Thank you.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           app:font="@{@string/font_1}" />

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="right"
           android:background="@null"
           android:gravity="center_vertical|right"            
           android:textSize="18sp"
           app:font="@{@string/font_2}" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```